# CakePHP Routing help

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to make my `/pages/about` become just `/about

I tried doing it with the routing in routes.php but couldn't get it working e.g. `Router::connect('/pages/about', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));`

can anyone help?

ALSO

for my portfolio controller I have it currently showing work like `/portfolio/view/102` but I would like to display it something like `/portfolio/view/Paperview_Magazine-102` where Paperview Magazine is the title of the post and 102 is the ID of the post. I have looked at the Cake Book but if someone could post up some code that'd be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a route for `/about`, you need to make a route for `/about`, not `/pages/about`:

```
Router::connect('/about',
                array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about'));
```

To use URLs like `/portfolio/view/Paperview_Magazine-102`, you can use standard routes, but you'll have to do a little work in the controller:

```
// PortfolioController
// $identifier == "Paperview_Magazine-102"

public function view($identifier) {
    if (!preg_match('/^(.+)-(\d+)$/', $identifier, $matches)) {
        // $identifier is not in format 'Title-Id'
        $this->cakeError('error404');
    }

    // $matches[1] == Paperview_Magazine
    // $matches[2] == 102

    $post = $this->Portfolio->read(null, $matches[2]);
    $this->set(compact('post'));
}
```

Comment: I've added that code to my controller but I still get urls like `/portfolio/view/102` do I need to add something to the routes.php file as well?

Comment: @Cameron You'll need to *make* the links appropriately as well of course. `$this->Html->link(array(…, Inflector::slug($post['title']) . '-' . $post['id']))`. That's *not* happening automagically.

Comment: Yeah but when visiting the actual url it doesn't work? ie. driz.co.uk/cake/portfolio/view/Paperview_Magazine-1

Comment: When clicking the links on the sidebar it returns an error and doesn't show the work items. e.g. http://driz.co.uk/cake/portfolio/view/Paperview_Magazine-2

Comment: @Cameron You need to break the problem down a bit more. It says you're trying to access an array index that's not there *in the view*. That has nothing to do with the code I provided above. Debug your variables using `debug()` at different stages to trace the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit of a long shot, but in the first one you could try Router::connect('/:controller/about', array('action'=>'display'));?  I seem to remember having some similar problems with my routes and this maybe helping, though I can't remember why.

With the second question, can't you just rework the view function so it accepts a $slug parameter instead of $id, and find the right portfolio record by searching on the slug instead?  Or check if the parameter is_numeric, and search for an id if it is, or a slug if it isn't...